# Database for an Android App

Tags: android, database, sqlite, mlab

Hey guys I'm working on an Android App with Android Studio and I need a database like mlab(mongoDB). But Android doesn't support mlab. I can't just use SQLite because my data has to be saved also when my application is not running.

For example if my user signs in, their profile photo and other information should be saved in the database and I also want to code something like a friend request which also should be saved in the database.

I googled so much but I didn't find a good solution.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Explain in more detail what do you mean by `I can't just use SQLite because my data has to be saved also when my application is not running.`

Comment: I explained it a little bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asking about two separate things. mLab is a Database as a Service which uses MongoDB, while SqLite is just a database.

You can save data while your application is not being used with either option, simply look into background Services and other parts of the Android API that allow background tasks.

If you want to save data to a database that is not on the device, you'll need to look into the documentation of the service to determine the best way to interact with your database. In the case of mLab, they allow both custom drivers and a REST API for interacting with your database.